# Orthogonal projection and normal operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $G$ be normal operator with compact resolvent such that $\ker G$ is different from $\{0\}$.

Now Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\ker G$ and consider $G' = G + P$.

Please, I want an explication to the following question:

How $0$ belongs to resolvent set of $G'$?

Comment: What do you mean by "compact resolvent"?

Comment: operator with compact resolvent means that its spectrum is disrete

Comment: So your operator is unbounded, then?

Comment: @Martin: The usual meaning is the literal one: an (unbounded) operator is said to have compact resolvent if its resolvent (at some, equivalently at all points of the resolvent set) is a compact operator. As you correctly point out, such an operator must be unbounded (unless you work in finite dimensions). Typical examples are differential operators whose resolvents are integral operators (which tend to be compact). Many operators arising in mathematical physics do have compact resolvents. The first theorem one proves about operators with compact resolvent is that the spectrum is discrete.

Comment: Now, I have another question:

Comment: what does it mean by analytic operator in the Kato sens

Comment: I would have a complete definition about it.